# How do I find if the particular removed user to check if they affected my other SE sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Can I have the name or profile of the user removed to see if they have affected the other SE sites I am on?

Comment: Given that profiles disappear from the public upon account deletion, and that the names revert back to the default userN format, I would guess *no*. I also very much doubt that there are really any reasons why you would need to know the identity of an account that got deleted (but if there were to be such a situation, you could just contact SE directly).

Comment: @T.Bongers to see if they were a down voting user used for the purpose of creating havoc on another. I have seen this.

Comment: If you have concerns about voting patterns like this, then contact the SE community managers. There isn't a reason for individual users to have access to this information in order to carry out their own investigation.

Comment: I would guess that you could find at least an approximation of the list of removed users comparing two consecutive data dumps in SEDE. (But I do not claim that this information could be in some way useful.) Related post on another meta: [Is it possible to know the list of removed users?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3629)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for you to find out which user was removed. This is not even possible for per-site moderators (although for obvious reasons we sometimes, yet not always, could guess it).

If you suspect there is a problem with your votes on some site, then signal it on that site to the per-site moderators (via a flag "other" for example). Or, write to SE, see "Contact" at the bottom of the page.

All that said, it seems there was a unique vote removed on your account. Naively, this does not strike me as a strong reason to suspect some conspiracy over numerous sites.